# CSSCAN for the character set change, database version 11.2.0.3.0

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

According to Document 745809.1, Installing Csscan.

While running the "Csminst.sql" we are getting below error

```
SQL> @$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/csminst.sql

create user csmig identified by csmig password expire account lock

*

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-28003: password verification for the specified password failed
```

Comment: Is CSSCAN still available for Oracle 11? Maybe disable password verification temporarily.

Comment: AFAIK csscan was made obsolete by the Oracle Database Migration Assistant for Unicode (DMU)

Answer (score 0):

You can just edit the file `$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/csminst.sql` and change `identified by csmig` from `csmig` to a more complex password; you may have to enclose the password with double quotes if you have characters other than alphanumeric, underscore (`_`), dollar sign (`$`) or pound/hash sign (`#`).

Example:

```
create user csmig identified by "W#$!?X8Y" password expire account lock;
```

Answer (score 0):

1 Just edit the script with minimum 8 characters including at least 1 digit
or
2 Disable password verification function.

Here is second method disabling password verification function

```
      SQL> select * from dba_profiles
          2  where profile='DEFAULT' and resource_name='PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION';

        PROFILE                                            RESOURCE_NAME                    RESOURCE LIMIT
        -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------------------
        DEFAULT                                            PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION         PASSWORD VERIFY_FUNCTION_11G

        "
        SQL> @csminst
        create user csmig identified by csmig password expire account lock
        *
        ERROR at line 1:
        ORA-28003: password verification for the specified password failed
        ORA-20001: Password length less than 8


        Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
        With the Partitioning, Oracle Label Security, OLAP, Data Mining
        and Real Application Testing options

       /*-- Disable password verify function temporarily-- */

     SQL> alter profile default LIMIT PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION  NULL;

        Profile altered.

        SQL> @csminst

        User created.


        Grant succeeded.


        Grant succeeded.


        Grant succeeded.


        Grant succeeded.


        Grant succeeded.


        Grant succeeded.


        Grant succeeded.


        User altered.


        0 rows created.


        1 row updated.


        Table created.


        Synonym dropped.


        Synonym created.


        Table created.


        Synonym dropped.


        Synonym created.


        Table created.


        Synonym dropped.


        Synonym created.


        Table created.


        Synonym dropped.


        Synonym created.


        Table created.


        Synonym dropped.


        Synonym created.


        Table created.


        Synonym dropped.


        Synonym created.


        Table created.


        Synonym dropped.


        Synonym created.


        Table created.


        Synonym dropped.


        Synonym created.


        Table created.


        Synonym dropped.


        Synonym created.


        Table created.


        Synonym dropped.


        Synonym created.


        Table created.


        Synonym dropped.


        Synonym created.


        Table created.


        Synonym dropped.


        Synonym created.


        18 rows created.


        View created.


        Synonym dropped.


        Synonym created.


        View created.


        Synonym dropped.


        Synonym created.


        View created.


        Synonym dropped.


        Synonym created.


        View created.


        Synonym dropped.


        Synonym created.


        View created.


        Synonym dropped.


        Synonym created.


        View created.


        Synonym dropped.


        Synonym created.


        View created.


        View created.


        View created.


        View created.


        Grant succeeded.


        Grant succeeded.

        Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
        With the Partitioning, Oracle Label Security, OLAP, Data Mining


        SQL> select username from dba_users
          2  where created  > sysdate-1;

        USERNAME
        ------------------------------
        CSMIG

        SQL> select * from dba_profiles
          2  where profile='DEFAULT' and resource_name='PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION';

        PROFILE                        RESOURCE_NAME                    RESOURCE LIMIT
        ------------------------------ -------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------------------
        DEFAULT                        PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION         PASSWORD NULL


    /* Enabling Password Verify function --*/
        SQL> alter profile default LIMIT PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION  VERIFY_FUNCTION_11G;

        Profile altered.

        SQL> select * from dba_profiles
          2  where profile='DEFAULT' and resource_name='PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION';

        PROFILE                        RESOURCE_NAME                    RESOURCE LIMIT
        ------------------------------ -------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------------------
        DEFAULT                        PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION         PASSWORD VERIFY_FUNCTION_11G

   /*-- Run a simple test to check password verify function enabled-- */
       SQL> create user test identified by test;
        create user test identified by test
        *
        ERROR at line 1:
        ORA-28003: password verification for the specified password failed
        ORA-20001: Password length less than 8
```

Comment: If you disable the password verification, be sure to re-enable it after you are finished!

Comment: Yes it was shown in last step ,enable and verifying that it was enabled.I prefer 1st method same as your step provided in your answer.